# Выравнивание меню

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Подскажите, как выравнить все пункты меню на одном уровне, а то последний пункт переносится на другую строку.

```
    <div class="navbar">
    <div class="container">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse text-">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="col-sm-2"><a href="#slide-1">Главная</a></li>
                <li class="col-sm-2"><a href="#slide-2">Услуги</a></li>
                <li class="col-sm-2"><a href="#slide-3">Text клиенты</a></li>
                <li class="col-sm-2"><a href="#slide-4">Text Text</a></li>
                <li class="col-sm-2"><a href="#slide-5">Text работы</a></li>
                <li class="col-sm-2"><a href="#slide-6">Отзывы</a></li>
                <li class="col-sm-2"><a href="#slide-7">Контакты</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2 active-menu"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Обновление**

Я написал следущий код

```
<ul class="nav m">
    <li class="col-sm-1"><a href="#slide-1">Главная</a></li>
    <li class="col-sm-2"><a href="#slide-2">Услуги</a></li>
    <li class="col-sm-2"><a href="#slide-3">Text клиенты</a></li>
    <li class="col-sm-2"><a href="#slide-4">Text Text</a></li>
    <li class="col-sm-2"><a href="#slide-5">Text работы</a></li>
    <li class="col-sm-2"><a href="#slide-6">Отзывы</a></li>
    <li class="col-sm-1"><a href="#slide-7">Контакты</a></li>
</ul>
```

Но пункты становятся кривыми. Как выровнять?

Comment: максимальная размернось строки 12 колонок, у вас 14

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Как уже писали, главная проблема - несоответствие Вашего меню и сетке bootstrap.
У вас 7 элементов меню. При сетке кратной 12-ти разместить 7 элементов нормально стредствами bootstrap не получится. Колонки точно будут не ровные.
Если Вы можете сократить меню на один элемент (например, сделать Отзывы как под-меню раздела Клиенты), то 6 элементов прекрасно встанут в сетку.

Если же такой возможности нет, то можно переорганизовать `<nav>` и его детей `<li>` как таблицу.

```
<div class="nav">
<a href="#slide-1">Главная</a>
<a href="#slide-2">Услуги</a>
<a href="#slide-3">Text клиенты</a>
<a href="#slide-4">Text Text</a>
<a href="#slide-5">Text работы</a>
<a href="#slide-6">Отзывы</a
<a href="#slide-7">Контакты</a>
</div>
```

И CSS

```
.nav { display: table-row; width: 100%; }
.nav>* { display: table-cell; }
```

В такой постановке есть плюсы и минусы.
**Плюс** в том, что Вы получаете свое горизонтальное меню. Работать будет как обычная `<table>`. И ширина колонок будет пропорциональна тексту.
Если хотите, чтобы ширина колонок была одинаковая, то устанавливаете ширину процентах. В вашем случае `100/7~14%`. Т.е. вот так:

```
.nav>* { display: table-cell; width: 14%; }
```

**Минус** же в том, что вы теряете bootstrapовскую адаптивную верстку. И Вам придется ее прописывать самостоятельно. Т.е. писать `media`, при котором

```
.nav>* { display: inline-block; width: auto; }
```

В зависимости от того, как это меню используется, могут повылезать еще проблемы с ориентацией меню, но это уже надо смотреть имея страницу и весь код...

Еще раз: если можно сократить менб всего лишь на один пункт - это решит ВСЕ проблемы. А я всего лишь предлагаю один из вариантов решения текущей постановки вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

Если сетка стандартная (12) колонок , то в примере ошибка, у Вас их больше.

А чтобы исключить переносы по ширине используй 

`white-space: nowrap`

Работает только для inline-block элементов, это запретит переносы в принципе

Comment: Обновил вопрос.